# (Done) Reopen request - question closed as unclear

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Dismissed on grounds of misconduct, without police involvement](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136953/dismissed-on-grounds-of-misconduct-without-police-involvement)

This was closed as unclear, which seems to be because the original version of the text was very brief and included an acronym that only has meaning in the UK. It's since been edited and now has a great answer, and it seems perfectly clear now. I voted to reopen, does anyone agree?

Comment: Agreed - Unsurprisingly I've already cast my VTRO!

Answer (score 2):

I've cast the last vote and the question has been reopened.